# NPM Live-server not installing on zsh

Tags: node.js, npm, zsh, npm-live-server

I have been trying to install live-server globally with:
`npm install -g live-server` but I keep on getting the error message below;

```
mac@Edozie ~ % npm install -g live-server
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated opn@6.0.0: The package has been renamed to `open`
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mac/.npm/_logs/2020-07-30T04_56_32_406Z-debug.log
```

I have followed every step in the tutorial, I am currently watching to install this but I kept getting this message. Please, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess, but modifying the permissions of your /usr/local/lib/node_modules might fix the install:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

I have messed things up before by modifying things in /usr/local/lib before though, so use at your own discretion.